# PHP Image save function

Tags: php, image, function, save

i've made this php function to resize picture , and i want to save it to folder but it can't , what is the problem ?

```
    function resize_sliku($slika,$sirina,$visina,$save){
list($width, $height) = getimagesize($slika) ;
$tn = imagecreatetruecolor($sirina, $visina) ;
$image = imagecreatefromjpeg($slika) ;
imagecopyresampled($tn, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $sirina, $visina, $width, $height) ;
imagejpeg($image, $save, 100) ;
}
```

$slika is the link of the picture , $sirina is the width , $visina is height and $save is the path to save..

Comment: what system are you running this on? linux?

Comment: What errors/warnings are you getting?

Comment: check inside apache's logs folder the error.log file and see what errors you get there. If not much, try setting you LogLevel to debug

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Target folder is writable? Change permissions to 0777.
UPD: $save is absolute path?

Comment: try `imagejpeg($image, null, 100);` Image outputed to browser?